# How do I embed a region of a site into another webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html

Is it possible to embed a certain portion of a site into a wordpress page? For example, If I want to embed stackoverflow to my site, and be able to scroll only to a predermined feel how would I accomplish this? 
I tried using

```
  <iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

But that only shows a tiny portion and not exactly what I want it to show.
Is there a better way to mimic an embedded element of another site to even mimic the scroll so it's like its really part of the site.The page source is too much to comb through.

Hope you guys can help!

Thanks i'm still a noob.

Comment: `Hoping javascript can do this` no, it can't, since javascript has no access to the content of the iframe of a cross origin site unless the cross origin site is written in such a way as to cooperate with your site - you can always change the size of the iframe though

Comment: perhaps with how it gets displayed on my site?

Comment: Unless you control both sites, you are flirting with disaster. What happens when the IFRAMEd site owners change something -- like the theme? or control names? or their page layout? Do you want to take the chance on having to continually develop changes to your site based on another one you can't control? I would be very cautious about any use of IFRAMEs to sites you do not control.

Comment: Best you can hope for is setting size of iframe and hope it is optimal enough for your users. Beyond that you can't do much else due to the *"same origin policy"* which you can easily look up what it means

Comment: Actually it is my site.

Comment: It is unfortunately not possible unless you have control over the website in the iframe. In order to control what is shown to the user it would require modification of the original side which you cannot do without access to their server. The best you can do is style the iframe properties (height, width, etc.) but outside of that you're out of luck.